# SSHd on Fedora 36 doesn't start after boot, even after systemctl enable sshd.service

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, reboot

When I boot my desktop sshd is not running:

```
=$ systemctl status sshd.service
○ sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
```

If I'll do `sudo systemctl enable sshd.service; sudo systemctl start sshd.service` it comes online without problem and status shows:

```
=$ sudo systemctl status sshd.service
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-10-25 12:25:47 CEST; 1min 11s ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 14091 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 76311)
     Memory: 2.3M
        CPU: 8ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
             └─ 14091 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"
 
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com sshd[14091]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com sshd[14091]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
```

But on next reboot - it's still down.

Last lines from `journalctl | grep sshd.service` don't show anything bad:

```
Oct 18 11:45:20 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[4936]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable sshd.service
Oct 18 11:45:27 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[5039]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Oct 18 11:45:28 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 11:45:28 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 11:51:40 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 11:51:41 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 18 11:51:41 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 11:56:37 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[3079]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable sshd.service
Oct 18 11:56:40 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[3114]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Oct 18 11:56:40 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 11:56:40 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 11:56:49 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 11:56:49 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 18 11:56:50 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 11:57:18 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 11:57:18 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 12:26:50 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 12:26:50 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 18 12:26:50 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 12:31:42 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 12:31:42 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 12:51:31 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 12:51:31 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 18 12:51:31 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 18 13:30:04 orange.home.depesz.com baloo_file_extractor[3719]: kf.baloo: "/home/depesz/tmp/old-orange/var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/sshd.service" id seems to have changed. Perhaps baloo was not running, and this file was deleted + re-created
Oct 18 17:02:51 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[41862]:   depesz : TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Oct 18 17:02:51 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 18 17:02:51 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 19 14:02:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 19 14:02:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 19 14:02:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 19 14:02:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Consumed 1.732s CPU time.
Oct 19 14:05:10 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 19 14:05:10 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 23 10:25:58 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 23 10:25:58 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 24 20:57:45 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 24 20:57:45 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 24 20:57:45 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 24 20:57:45 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Consumed 2.378s CPU time.
Oct 25 07:50:08 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[8157]:   depesz : TTY=pts/10 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable sshd.service
Oct 25 07:50:10 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[8275]:   depesz : TTY=pts/10 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Oct 25 07:50:10 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 25 07:50:10 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 25 11:44:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 25 11:44:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 25 11:44:24 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 25 12:25:37 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[13952]:   depesz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl enable sshd.service
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[14088]:   depesz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Starting sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 25 12:25:47 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Started sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 25 12:26:30 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[14226]:   depesz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service
Oct 25 12:26:58 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[14388]:   depesz : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status sshd.service
Oct 25 12:27:48 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopping sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon...
Oct 25 12:27:48 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 25 12:27:48 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: Stopped sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon.
Oct 25 12:40:37 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[7448]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status sshd.service
Oct 25 12:40:48 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[7604]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status sshd.service
Oct 25 12:40:54 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[7672]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status sshd.service
Oct 25 12:41:15 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[7772]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status sshd.service
Oct 25 12:41:49 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[7988]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service
Oct 25 12:42:20 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[8147]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service -n 100
Oct 25 12:42:25 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[8214]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service -n 50
Oct 25 12:42:28 orange.home.depesz.com sudo[8286]:   depesz : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/depesz ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service -n 50
```

Any idea on how to fix/debug it?

Ah, as final note - there is nothing listening on :22 after reboot. And I can start sshd.service without any problem using `systemctl start sshd.service`

Comment: There might be clues on what is going on in the lines you remove with your `grep`. Show all journal entries from a start to a stop, with some margin, e.g. `journalctl --since 11:56:35 --until 11:56:55`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log shows the `sshd.service` being actively deactivated, for example here:

```
Oct 25 12:27:48 orange.home.depesz.com systemd[1]: sshd.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

So someone or something is doing `sudo systemctl disable sshd.service`, thereby instructing `systemd` not to start `sshd` during the next system startup.

You need to investigate who or what is doing that, and fix it accordingly.

Comment: Any idea on how? It is my desktop machine, noone uses it but me, and I definitely didn't disable sshd

Comment: The usual way in a business environment: activate and check logs, correlate times with other system activities, check those other activities. But your comment seems to imply that this is not a business environment, and hence offtopic on Server Fault.

Comment: Not entirely sure what business environemnt has to do with anything - it is a server, so serverfault should be relevant? Or am I missing something? Anyway - I'll try to figure it out, too bad that there isn't any trail that would tell me what caused that :(

Comment: The official topic definition of Server Fault is: "questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment"

Comment: Ah, sorry then. What would be the place to ask about linux/unix-related issues at home? Also, where can i see this "official topic definition"? I don't see text anywhere on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: The topic definition is at https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic . An appropriate site for home IT questions would be https://superuser.com .

Comment: OK. thanks. will try to remember.